# Is it possible to access Databricks DBFS from Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, etl, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I am trying to use the Copy Data Activity to copy data from Databricks DBFS to another place on the DBFS, but I am not sure if this is possible.

When I select Azure Delta Storage as a dataset source or sink, I am able to access the tables in the cluster and preview the data, but when validating it says that the tables are not delta tables (which they aren't, but I don't seem to acsess the persistent data on DBFS)

Furthermore, what I want to access is the DBFS, not the cluster tables. Is there an option for this?

Comment: You should use the notebook activity in ADF to interact with DBFS

Comment: Thanks for answering! Could you elaborate on that? I could create a notebook that writes DBFS to another format (eg delta), read that into ADF and then do the same thing the other way around for the sink, is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Though on a side note, once you have data in delta lake, you can also branch off using the native ADF delta lake connector.

Comment: @user3216754 Data Factory can not access it directly, but we can achieve that in code level like Ruaunak Jhawar said in comment.